# Does IMAP "LIST" command return "NO" code

Tags: python, exception, imap, imaplib

I'm implementing on top of `imap` python builtin library and I'm trying to find if `IMAP4.list([directory[, pattern]])` method can return `NO` code and when.

According to the RFC, it could.

Exemple of code :

```py
from imaplib import IMAP4_SSL

with IMAP4_SSL(host=IMAP_SERVER) as imap_connection:
  imap_connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
  
  code, data = imap_connection.list()

  if code == "NO":
    print("Does this case exists ?")
```

[IMAP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501)
[Python imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.list)

Comment: My quick reading of the RFC, you would get that if you pass in an invalid argument; like I guess an invalid directory name.

Comment: I have tested what you sugested but the IMAP server reply "OK" with empty list of mailboxes.

Comment: I'm guessing try a few more mail servers. If neither of Gmail, Dovecot, Exchange, or Courier does this, I guess that's enough to conclude that it's unimportant.

Comment: It's permitted but unlikely.  How does it hurt to handle the case?

Comment: IIRC the only way to get a NO is with uncommon combinations of [access control](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4314) settings.